# Nuxt.js + Vagrant + Homestead port forwarding

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vagrant, homestead

I am unable to connect to  my Nuxt.js application **OUTSIDE** the vagrant box (aka. my host or local machine), but it's able to retrieve content **INSIDE** the vagrant box.

So...

I'm using Laravel Homestead to host my Nuxt.js application and I start the server inside the vagrant box by

```
nuxt start --public 0.0.0.0:3000
```

I can confirm that it's running and a message shows that it's listening to **localhost:3000** and 
`curl localhost:3000` returns the application content.

I have also checked my **homestead.yaml** config and I have port forwarding setup there.

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 8192
cpus: 4
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:/Developments
      to: /home/vagrant/projects

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/public

databases:
    - homestead

ports:
    - send: 9200
      to: 9200
    - send: 5601
      to: 5601
    - send: 3000
      to: 3000
```

What have I done wrong? other applications such as Elasticsearch and Kibana seems to run fine and can be accessed on my local/host machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added this part to my package.json and now it's working

```
    "config": {
    "nuxt": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": "3000"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I was using this before the latest updates on windows 10, after that it doesn't work, can anyone help?

Comment: By what url do you access it from your host machine?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package to run the NUXT app.

```
cross-env HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000 nuxt start
```